# logic for guitar hero style game in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, timing

I am trying to create a game with a similar structure to Guitar hero. Shapes are created at left side of the screen and animate to a 'hit area' on the right. The idea obviously is that the shapes reach the hit area at the correct point in the song.

I am currently working out the exact time each shape should reach the hit area, aware that it will take 4 seconds for the shape to animate across the screen.

Basically, at the start of the song I am using TweenMax delayed call for every shape required in the song at the beginning. the delay Im using has been pre-calculated as the time it will take for the shape to animate minus the animation time.

```
TweenMax.delayedCall(1, createShape, [params]);
TweenMax.delayedCall(3, createShape, [params]);
TweenMax.delayedCall(5.5, createShape, [params]);
TweenMax.delayedCall(11, createShape, [params]);
TweenMax.delayedCall(17, createShape, [params]);
```

etc...

obviously I am using a loop and I'm extracting the delays and all other info from an xml doc.

I would imagine there is a much better way of doing this but i have searched and cant find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use TweenMax.killDelayedCallsTo, there is probably no reason to use TweenMax.delayedCall over flash.utils.setTimeout :)

```
setTimeout(createShape, 5500 /* ms */, param1, param2, param3);
```

That said, setTimeout is not really "better" in any way. You could only win some bytes in swf size if this was the only place where you used TweenMax.

Another way of doing this would be placing your songs in FLVs (with no video) and using cue points to create shapes. IMO this has no real advantages vs your method, except in case you play songs online and user connectivity causes pauses (in which case the experience sucks any way).

Comment: Thanks, Im using TweenMax quite a bit in the project so I'll stick with that.